# Return all elements from a list

Tags: clojure

I have a function

```
(defn my-fn [a b & args]
  [a
   (for [arg args]
    (into [] (butlast arg)))
   b])
```

If I do `(my-fn [1 2] [3 4] [5 6 2] [7 8 3])`

It returns `[[1 2] ([5 6] [7 8]) [3 4]]`

I want the output to be `[[1 2] [5 6] [7 8] [3 4]]` but I cannot figure out how to do this

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I'd `into` `[a]` all your mapped values and then `conj` `b` at the end.  E.g.

```
(defn my-fn [a b & args]
  (-> [a]
      (into (map (comp vec butlast) args))
      (conj b)))
```

Comment: this is the most elegant

Answer (score 1):

and one more variant, using quote and unquote splicing:

```
user> (defn my-fn2 [a b & args]
        `[~a ~@(map (comp vec butlast) args) ~b])
;;=> #'user/my-fn2

user> (my-fn2 [1 2] [3 4] [5 6 2] [7 8 3])
;;=> [[1 2] [5 6] [7 8] [3 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```
(defn my-fn [a b & args]
  (vec
    (concat
      [a]
      (for [arg args]
        (into [] (butlast arg)))
      [b])))

(my-fn [1 2] [3 4] [5 6 2] [7 8 3])
   => [[1 2] [5 6] [7 8] [3 4]]
```

Please note that `concat` returns a lazy list, which for larger and/or more complicated problems [can cause a StackOverflowException](https://stuartsierra.com/2015/04/26/clojure-donts-concat). The outer `vec` converts the lazy list in to a concrete vector. It is unnecessary for this example and you could remove it if you want.

As another note, `concat` expects each argument to be a list/vector, so I have wrapped `a` and `b` into 1-element vectors. The output of `for` is already a (lazy) list.

---

Because `conj`, `cons`, `concat`, etc can be somewhat non-intuitive in their behavior, you may wish to checkout the helper functions `glue`, `append`, `prepend`, & friends [in the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#gluing-together-like-collections).

---

## Background

Suppose we have a mixture of scalars & vectors (or lists) that we want to combine into a single vector. We want a function ??? to give us the following result:

```
(???  1 2 3 [4 5 6] 7 8 9)  =>  [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

Clojure doesn’t have a function for this. Instead we need to wrap all of the scalars into vectors and then use glue or concat:

```
; can wrap individually or in groups
(glue [1   2   3] [4 5 6] [7   8   9])  =>  [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]   ; could also use concat
(glue [1] [2] [3] [4 5 6] [7] [8] [9])  =>  [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]   ; could also use concat
```

It may be inconvenient to always wrap the scalar values into vectors just to combine them with an occasional vector value. Instead, it might be more convenient to unwrap the vector values, then combine the result with other scalars. We can do that [with the `->vector` and `unwrap` functions](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#combining-scalars-and-vectors):

```
(->vector 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)             =>  [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
(->vector 1 (unwrap [2 3 4 5 6 7 8]) 9)  =>  [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

It will also work recursively for nested `unwrap` calls:

```
(->vector 1 (unwrap [2 3 (unwrap [4 5 6]) 7 8]) 9)  =>  [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

Comment: I upvoted this as the first part of the answer is a good explanation of what mechanics are at play here and how to do what you want using standard Clojure constructs. I would guess that the downvote is for the distracting digression into how to do this with tupelo's functions. It's not exactly useless, because it is cool to think about this problem "backwards" as you have done, but it is a lot of 
text that is obviously copied from your readme without tailoring it to this specific question.

Comment: (And for what it's worth, I think `->vector` and `unwrap` are silly functions, since as shown in leetwinski's answer, the clojure built-in syntax-quote does this more flexibly and more tersely. But there's nothing wrong with explaining how you could implement the same thing yourself, as you've done.)

Comment: I have long wished for an "unwrap" function w/o needing to use the macro-oriented back-quote and unquote-splicing operators. This question directly motivated me to create the  `->vector` and `unwrap` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` statement returns a list.

```
(defn my-fn [a b & args]
    (->> [[a]
         (map (comp vec butlast) args)
         [b]]
      (apply concat)
      vec))
```

The final `vec` transform your seq into a vector.

Answer (score 0):

## Alternate Solution Using Python-Style Generator Functions

You could also solve it this way:

```
(ns tst.clj.core
  (:use clj.core tupelo.test)
  (:require [tupelo.core :as t] ))
(t/refer-tupelo)

(defn my-fn [a b & args]
  (lazy-gen
    (yield a)
    (yield-all (for [arg args]
                 (into [] (butlast arg))))
    (yield b)))

(my-fn [1 2] [3 4] [5 6 2] [7 8 3]) => ([1 2] [5 6] [7 8] [3 4])
```

Here `lazy-gen` creates a context for a "generator function", where successive values are added to the output list using the `yield` and `yield-all` functions. Note that the `yield-all` function is like the Clojure "unquote-splicing" operator `~@` and "unwraps" its sequence into the output stream.

An even easier answer is to dive deeper into the `for` part of your original solution to apply the `yield` output tap:

```
(defn my-fn2 [a b & args]
  (lazy-gen
    (yield a)
    (doseq [arg args]
      (yield (butlast arg)))
    (yield b)))

(my-fn2 [1 2] [3 4] [5 6 2] [7 8 3]) => ([1 2] (5 6) (7 8) [3 4])
```

This version of the solution follows your original logic more closely, 
and avoids the accidental complexity of the `for` function wrapping its results into a sequence, which conflicts with the `a` and `b` values not being wrapped in a vector. We also no longer need the `(into [] ...)` part of the original function.

Note that we have replaced the `for` with `doseq` since:

- We are no longer using the return value of the loop
- And, therefore, a lazy solution would never run